# How would I listen for simulated key presses in Python (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, keyboard, keyboard-events, pynput

I'm trying to create an accessibility controller for the Nintendo Switch using a Raspberry Pi and USB HID peripherals.  To do this, I am having one application read input via HID (and pressing the corresponding key, *see keyboard-input.py*) while having another application listen for input (see *keyboard-listener.py*).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get this working successfully.  When running the snippets below, keys pressed with pynput aren't caught by its listener.  I've also tried a variant using keyboard vice pynput, to no avail.  Is there a way to listen for these inputs?

---

*keyboard-listener.py*

```py
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press( key ):
    print( key )

def on_release( key ):
    print( key )

listener = keyboard.Listener( on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release )
listener.start()

# Run an endless loop...
```

*keyboard-input.py*

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press( 'a' )
keyboard.release( 'a' )
```

---

Edit 1:  As mentioned above, the variant I tried using keyboard is shown below.

*keyboard-listener.py*

```py
import keyboard

def print_key( event ):
    print( event )

keyboard.on_press( print_key )

# Run an endless loop...
```

*keyboard-input.py*

```py
import keyboard

keyboard.press( 'a' )   
keyboard.release( 'a' )

# ...or keyboard.press_and_release( 'a' ). Same result.
```